# Amount of rep suddenly went down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I am curious as to why/how my rep has gone down by 32 in the past couple of hours - there is nothing on my profile as to why.  It seems something I replied to and had edited (3 upvotes + edit).

Is this due to an account deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a checkbox "show removed posts" on the reputation tab of your profile, if you enable it you can see which removed posts are responsible for the loss of reputation.

In this case the reason is that I removed questions posted by a known troll and you had answered one of those.

Comment: No worries, am not upset at all about it, just curious.  Thank you for the profile tip as well.

Comment: Don't feed the trolls :)

Comment: @MattDMo sometimes it is hard to tell who is a troll and who is someone who, for whatever reason, wrote a bad question/answer.